# Facebook/Twitter share button - specify url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter

I'm trying to implement Facebook share (not like) and Twitter tweet buttons into my Rails 3 app. I've looked at a couple different gems (shareable, facebook_share, social-buttons, social-share button etc.) but they don't quite fit the bill. I want the button to be a real share button, not a like button. I also want to be able to specify the url. Does anyone know of a good gem to accomplish this?

Alternatively, how tough is it to role your own for something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Koala and Twitter gem fit the bill pretty well. 
They are a wrapper on top of their respective API's so you have maximum control over what you want to do.

https://github.com/arsduo/koala
https://github.com/sferik/twitter